# Why use simple cubic reciprocal lattice vector to determine Miller indices?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

Bragg diffraction: 
$$ d_{hkl}= \frac{\lambda}{2sin(\theta)}.$$

This equation would allow us to determine the lattice spacing ($d_{hkl}$) of parallel crystal planes given that we observe an intensity spike at $2\theta$ using x-ray powder diffraction. From the equation:

$$ d_{hkl}^{2} = \frac{4\pi^2}{|G_{hkl}|^{2}},$$ where $G_{hkl}$ defines the reciprocal lattice vector, we would be able to find the hkl values. Then, using forbidden reflection rules for a crystal structure, we could determine the crystal structure.

For simple cubic $|G_{hkl}|^{2}=\frac{4\pi^{2}}{a^2}(h^2+k^2+l^2)$, with a being the distance between two corners of a cubic cell.
So,

$$\frac{(h^2+k^2+l^2)}{a^2}=\frac{1}{d_{hkl}^2}.$$

Since this is for a simple cubic cell, why does this allow us to determine the crystal structure of something that has a bcc or fcc structure? Each structure within the cubic set should have different $G_{hkl}$ vector. This is where I am confused.

The book I am using is Fundamentals of Condensed Matter by Sidebottom.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean here: "Each structure within the cubic set".

Comment: Sorry. I meant the set within the cubic crystal family (i.e. simple cubic, body centered, and face centered).

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: you can always choose a primitive cell. If you choose a body-centred cell let's say, then you are choosing to index your reflections with the constraint that you only have even values of $h+k+l$. Is you question about how you relate such a bcc to a primitive cell?

Comment: Excuse my confusion. The equation above relating $h^2+k^2+l^2$ to $\frac{1}{d_{hkl}}$ is the essence of my question. This relation is derived using a simple cubic (primitive cell) $G_{hkl}$. However, this relation somehow allows us to determine reflections that obey the bcc rules (even sums of hkl). What I would think is that I would have to rederive another relation using the bcc $G_{hkl}$. But clearly it is standard to just use the one with the primitive cell. I'm starting to just accept that it is because the primitive cell takes on all hkl. Then again that is unsatisfying.